# A Friend With Three Different Characters

Tags: riddle, wordplay, story

> I had an unusual friend. He was very useful to me and we made many fascinating discoveries together. Sometimes, though, he would wake up entirely backwards.
>   On those days he would not work with me but instead with an accountant who found him very useful as well. The odd thing was that in the accountant's office,
>   everyone insisted that my friend was short. When he worked with me, although he may have been in a technical sense short, we seldom thought of him that way. 
>   People generally regarded him as full sized, perhaps a bit informal.
>   One day, my friend had a terrible accident and completely fell to pieces. I tried to put him back together but I must have gotten something wrong because
>   instead of his old life he now lives in a church and hangs around the priest.

Can you identify my friend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> LAB

Because

> You make lots of fascinating discoveries in a lab

Then

> When backwards you are BAL, which is short for Balance

Then

> Lab is also short and informal for laboratory

Then

> When you put him back together you put him back as an ALB. The alb is a long, white linen liturgical vestment with tapered sleeves. A priest wears this

Comment: Well done! The title is also meant to suggest that the answer has three letters.

Comment: Ah, yes I did notice that and forgot to explain that